# handle special character in xsl for valid JSON

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I have xml that contains special character and i am using xsl to convert this xml to json. However it is generating invalid json with parse error.

here is my input xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <mydata>
    <data1>
      <Description>670054 [   CS\48] AGSB ON ROAD</Description>
    </data1>
  </mydata>
</root>
```

XSL that i am trying-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        {
        "Data":[{
        "ShortDescription":<xsl:value-of select="root/mydata/data1/Description"/>
        }]}
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output-

```
 {
        "Data":[

            {
            "Id": "670054",
"ShortDescription": "670054 [   CS\48] AGSB ON ROAD"

        ]
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: There is no way you can convert XML to JSON with XSLT 1.0, which is the version I suppose you are using here. Real JSON support is not available before XSLT 3.0. I recommend using a different tool. What do you have available?

Comment: The expected output doesn't seem to be valid JSON to me or any online JSON linter or validator. In general, XSLT 1 is not a simple tool to transform XML to JSON, XSLT 3 has built-in conversion functions, JSON map and array data types and a `json` serialization method. So which XSLT processor on which platform do you use exactly?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, the backslash in `\4` also would need to be escaped.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i am using XSLT 1.0 processor on windows. i have to achieve this using xsl. can't we use any external library ?

Comment: Using an external library with XSLT depends on the particular XSLT processor used, you haven't explained which one you use. And at least for that provided sample it seems questionable why you need XSLT at all if the JSON creation is delegated to an external library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i found one solution to resolve this issue for valid json.

```
<xsl:template name="handleBackSlash">
 <xsl:param name="string" select="."/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string, '\')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($string, '\'), '\\' )"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="handleBackSlash">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '\')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

then call template-

```
 <xsl:call-template name="handleBackSlash">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="Description"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: That's a good start, but in order to ensure valid JSON you also need to escape quotes, horizontal tabs and line feeds.

Comment: Yes . same way we can handle other special character . In my case it was backslash so i found this one.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 3.0 includes functionality to output JSON. In earlier versions you can do it "by hand" using the text output method, which is what you are doing here. But then it's entirely your responsibility to format the output JSON correctly, including in particular escaping of special characters such as quotes, newlines, and backslashes. That's easy enough in XSLT 2.0 using the replace() function; it's rather more convoluted in XSLT 1.0, though exslt.org has some templates you can incorporate into your stylesheet, such as str:replace.

When you ask questions about XSLT on this site, do please say which XSLT version(s) you are able to use. It often makes a difference to the answer. The problem is that XSLT 1.0 is now very old, but (like COBOL) many people still seem to be using it.

Comment: Can't we achieve this by using any external library with xslt 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such library. If you want an XSLT processor that understands JSON, you need one that's been continuously developed over the years, such as Saxon or Altova.